# Find the value of $1-2\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the value of $1-2\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta$

I have done so far: $1-2\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\cdot \sin^2\theta$

$1-2\sin^2\theta+\sin^2\theta\cdot sin^2\theta$

$1-\sin^2\theta\cdot (2+\sin^2\theta)$

$\cos^2\theta\cdot (3-\cos^2\theta)$

$3\cos^2\theta-\cos^4\theta$

Comment: There is a minus sign error in the calculation. You might note that the expression you started with is $(1-\sin^2\theta)^2$.

Comment: Try making the substitution $x=sin^2( \theta )$, and then applying the quadratic equation. Then work backwards.

Comment: thank you @AndréNicolas,@alfred Yerger,@Hagen von Eitzen

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
1 - 2 \sin^{2}\theta + \sin^{4}\theta = (1 - \sin^{2}\theta)^{2} = (\cos^{2}\theta)^{2} = \cos^{4}\theta
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The step where you introduce $\cos\theta$ is suspicious. Note that you do *not* have $(1-\sin^2\theta)\cdot (2+\sin^2\theta)$. Try what Alfred Yerger suggested. doens't $1-2x+x^2$ ring a bell?